# Jquery declare int? variable in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Good day,

I have an asp.net mvc4 project where I tried declare variable in jquery. Problem to be concluded in next: my data get from the model `@Model.EducationProgramBachelorId` and the property `EducationProgramBachelorId` in my class declared as `int?`. And when i try declare it in my jquery code:

```
var progId = @Model.EducationProgramBachelorId;
```

R# told me that `int? University.EducationProgramBachelorId Syntax Error`

I need this variable in my `if/else` condition where i want to do next:

```
if(progId != null){
//Do something
}
else{
//Do something
}
```

My questions is:

1. How can I declare `int?` variable in jquery?
2. In `if` statement when it's `true` I need write just `return` for that my function is closed or something else?

**EDIT**

Here is the part of my RAZOR page:

```
@model Models.Entities.University

@Html.DropDownList("EducationProgramBachelorId", String.Empty)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EducationProgramBachelorId)

<script type="text/jscript">

$(document).ready(function () {
        var progId = @Model.EducationProgramBachelorId; //here is I have an error and function didn't work
        if(progId != null){
            return;
        }
        else{
            $.getJSON('/Administrator/ProgramList/' + 1, function (data) {
                var items = '<option>Select a Program</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, program) {
                    items += "<option value='" + program.Value + "'>" + program.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#EducationProgramBachelorId').html(items);
            });
        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: you don't need to declare a variable as an int in javascript. Where are you seeing the error? it doesn't look like a javascript error at all.

Comment: Is ReSharper telling you that there's an error, or is the compiler or runtime telling you that there's an error?  ReSharper could be mistaken.

Comment: After this line of code var progId = @Model.EducationProgramBachelorId I have red wavy line where have my error

Comment: @BorHunter is that line in a .js file or an asp.net page?  We need more information.  It sounds to me like that should be in some javascript but it's not.

Comment: @BorHunter: I've had issues in the past where Visual Studio didn't understand a mix of Razor code and JavaScript code in a View.  But that doesn't prevent it from actually working.  Does the code compile?  Does it run?  Are there *actual* errors or just intellisense errors?

Comment: @Archer this line inside <script> in the my .cshtml page

Comment: @David Code compile, but function didn't work with this conclusion, but working perfectly outside

Comment: @BorHunter: Define "function didn't work with this conclusion, but working perfectly outside."  If the actual issue is in the JavaScript code then show what the resulting JavaScript code is.  Are there errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: ^^^ That, and show us the whole function

Comment: @BorHunter: You've updated to show the view code, but what does the resulting JavaScript code *in the browser* end up being?  If the JavaScript code "doesn't work" then you'll want to look at the actual JavaScript code to determine why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a nullable `int?` property is rendered to the view, it will not output anything. Can you create a new property in your model that will convert the `int?` to a normal int? Then return a zero if the EducationProgramBachelorId variable is null.

```
public int EducationProgramBachelorJSInt
{
    get
    {
        return EducationProgramBachelorId.HasValue ? 
        EducationProgramBachelorId.Value : 0;
    }
}
```

Then your JQuery code will look like this.

```
var progId = @Model.EducationProgramBachelorJSInt;
if(progId != 0){
    //Do something
}
else{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
 var progId = @(Model.EducationProgramBachelorId.HasValue ? Model.EducationProgramBachelorId : 0);
```

Thus if `Model.EducationProgramBachelorId` is null its `progId` will be set to `0`